# What do you call the diagonal bars as often seen in radio towers?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a specific word for these diagonal bars? I doubt engineers would call them diagonal bars since they're widely used in engineering, radio towers and bridges off my head use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **[cross bracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_bracing)**--diagonal supports used to reinforce the structure of a building or bridge or similar.

Individually, the bars might be called beams or girders.

Comment: The word I would have offered is in your answer: "supports".

Comment: I don't feel this answer gives enough context. thats why I made my answer,

Answer (score 2):

The overall structure might be called a [space frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_frame), although that term is more often used for structures that cover, roof, or enclose an area, rather than support a tower. Still the bascic structure of triangular bracing is similar.

Answer (score 2):

In Structural Engineering, this kind of building group is called **Trusses**. Trusses are a Structure that is made from 3 Sides, as the triangle is considered the Strongest Shape to build with. That said, they use it to create **Cross-Bracing** made up of **Members** as they are called; **Beams or Girders** (Horizontal Members), **Columns or Posts** (Vertical Members) and **Panels** (Wall/Cover Members).

A good truss reference: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/truss